# How can I change this php.ini setting when hosting a website with fortrabbit.com?

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, fortrabbit

**How can I change this php.ini setting when hosting a website with fortrabbit.com?**

- Desired value: always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
- Hosting Plan: "Light"
- PHP Version 5.6 (Don't want to use PHP 7.x)

**What I have tried**

- fortrabbit.com Admininterface

  - Result: "always_populate_raw_post_data" is not configurable there
- Set php.ini values via .htaccess in Document Root

  - Result: 500 Server error
- Created a second php.ini in my documentroot with the desired value

  - Result #1: Nothing
  - Result #2: phpinfo() shows "none" in "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"
  - Result #3: phpinfo() shows "none" in "Additional .ini files parsed"
- Tried to edit the /etc/php/php.ini

  - Result: Could not save the file, I'm not root on this server

**Why I would like this to work**

- I want to run Typo3 7.6
- Typo3 install tool complains about the missing php.ini setting
- I like the features, that fortrabbit.com offers
- I'm not affiliated/payed by fortrabbit.com

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? That setting only affects PHP 5.6 and was removed in PHP 7.0

Comment: depends on what type of hosting you opted for. Is it shared, VPS or dedicated? Also, what control panel have you got?

Comment: - PHP Version is 5.6, Type of hosting is "managed VPS", Controlpanel is custom

Comment: Just a suggestion as some hosting do allow to overwrite php settings with your custome php.ini. Place a file "php.ini" in the root folder of your domain with just the above setting in it. It worked for me in hostmonster hosting where I wanted to change few other values. Also try using the "ini_set()" to set the value via PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's valid, but I won't try this: "ini_set()" to set the value via PHP. Why? Because fortrabbit.com is a dedicated PHP Hoster. I expect them to solve such obstacles for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author does not want to change anything on his own and should work out a solution with the service provider instead.

Comment: Please contact the fortrabbit support. We'll happily apply any custom PHP ini setting to any of your Apps

Comment: @ukautz: Thx, just send a mail to the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:

Q: **How can I change this php.ini setting when hosting a website with fortrabbit.com?**

A: I cannot change this php.ini setting myself: always_populate_raw_post_data = -1. Had to ask support of fortrabbit.com. They did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using  **[ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)** function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's valid, but I won't try this: "ini_set()" to set the value via PHP. Why? Because fortrabbit.com is a dedicated PHP Hoster. I expect them to solve such obstacles for me.

Comment: If you don't want to find a solution how to configure your hosting setup on your own (given the means to do so by your provider), then why are you asking here? Contact your them and let them fix it for you (or they tell you that you have to configure it yourself or that there is no way to change it).

Comment: I think ini_set is the only solution you have here @DepriCat